# How can I convert a small amount of USD in my PayPal account to USD banknotes in Germany?

Tags: fees, international-transfer, paypal

I have a small amount of USD (about $200) in my PayPal account, and I want to withdraw that amount and get USD banknotes. I live in Germany, and I only have bank accounts in EUR.

The simple method would be this:

1. I send my PayPal account's USD to my EUR bank account. In this step, I lose some money to currency conversion and transfer costs.
2. Then, I withdraw the money from an ATM as EUR banknotes. This might have additional costs, but they are avoidable. If I use an ATM from my own bank, it is free.
3. Lastly, I exchange my EUR banknotes for USD banknotes at a currency exchange. However, currency exchanges have terrible rates (it is not uncommon to see a 30% difference between the buy and sell prices).

If I were to go with this method, I would lose a lot of money to currency conversion costs. The USD->EUR->USD conversion is something that I would want to avoid.

I could solve my problem by opening a USD bank account, but doing this for a single transaction seems like an overkill.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Note that the 30% spread you see is including the spread in both directions. If you see 30% spread between buy and ask at an fx shop, the midpoint is probably the true live rate (which you can check easy enough, just google "EURUSD" and it will come right up). So the amount of effort to put into this, is however much $30 is worth to you. Worth an hour of your time sure; worth opening a bank account, definitely not.

Comment: I can finally understand your question, after staring at it for a very long time. I have edited it to make things clearer. Can you check that everything is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Find someone who wants to do the opposite FX transaction (you have USD and want EUR, they have EUR and want USD, or vice versa), and swap the currencies with them. This works whenever you have one currency, they have another currency, and you are happy to trade. You’d pick the mid-range rate, and both parties avoid commercial fees.

Travellers often have small amounts of leftover currency. Try asking around at your workplace if your immediate circle of friends can’t help. But be careful about personal security - don’t announce on social media that you’ll be leaving your house empty over Christmas, for example.

Outside of that, you’ll need to use the avenues you’ve already explored.

Comment: You think to the opposite, i.e. someone who wants EUR (and has an EUR bank account by a local bank) and has USD? Very nice idea, the problem is that I am a foreigner here and I know no one. :-) But anyways thanks, the idea is very good!

Comment: @GraySheep No. You have USD, and you want EUR. So you look for someone who has EUR and wants your USD

Comment: Great answer - $200 is a great amount for a tourist to want; save probably $30 in lost conversion %.

Comment: @Flux No, I want USD banknotes. I have zero contact with anything USD-related, except an USA company paying me on paypal for my remote work. I use this to pay for everything, except that I would want to give a gift in the form of USA banknotes to my wife (USD banknotes are effectively a curiosity here). However, she will ask the conversion prices and if it is too big, she will be angry; and I do not want to lie to she. I want her to be happy to the notes. So I need to find a way to convert a little amount of paypal $ to banknote $.

Comment: @GraySheep Could you please edit your question's title and body? Your comment seems to contradict your question. In the question title and body, it looks like you have USD and want to convert it to EUR.

Comment: @Flux Possibly it was not enough clear in the question that I want USD banknotes, although I think it is visible in the body: the way what I dislike, had been an USD (paypal) -> EUR (bank account) -> EUR (banknotes) -> USD (banknote) conversion. This makes clear that USD banknotes is the end of the transaction path. I think my personal motives are not important here, I only wrote it to make clear, that I want USD banknotes.